# Possibilities of SQL Injection with EFCTP and .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, security, sql-injection

Just want to know from experts that is there any inbuilt security for SQL Injection in Entity Framework or .net MVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only built in if you use it. Entity Framework provides strongly typed entity classes - if you only use Linq to Entities you will be protected against SQL injection attacks, the same is true though if you use parametrized SQL with SQL server directly.

Having said that, you can still shoot yourself in the foot if you use EF store queries - this can be plain old SQL - so make sure you use `SqlParameter` here.